C++ App crashes on std::minmax_element with Visual Studio 2022 (>= 17.10)
The newest version of Visual Studio C++ compiler broke our code. Our application uses STL algorithm like std::minmax_element on measured samples. Sometimes the devices do not deliver a valid sample and a NaN element is inserted instead.
Up to now the STL algorithms ignored NaN completely (GCC, CLANG, Visual Studio).
The crash is reproducible with this minimum example:
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const double inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    const double nan = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    double values[] = {0, -inf, nan};
    const auto mm = std::minmax_element(std::begin(values), std::end(values));
    std::cout << "Min: " << *mm.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max: " << *mm.second << std::endl;
    return std::distance(mm.first, mm.second);
}

Playground: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GhTPsfj5q
Expected:
example.cpp
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
example.cpp
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 1
Min: -inf
Max: nan

VS 2022 >= 17.10
example.cpp
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
example.cpp
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 4294967295
Min: -inf
Max: 0

The STL expert from MS arguments that STL algorithms expect "strictly-weak-ordering". A sequence containing NaN does not fulfill this requirement and therefore we wander the world of undefined behavior.
A STL expert from my team understands the standard so that strictly-weak-ordering is only needed in C++-20 when using std::less.
Still, I need to know, if we have to cleanup our data sequences upfront, before calling STL algorithms in future to be safe.

Either you have to clean your data of NaNs or write comparator function that compares NaNs equal and orders those somewhere, for example to be less than -std::numeric_limits::infinity()

You said the algorithm used to ignore NaN, but you show expected output with "Max: NaN", which means it wasn't ignored. Is that really what you meant? It doesn't match your description (and zero really is the largest non-NaN value)

Works as expected in VS2022 version 17.10.5 in Debug and Release in C++17, C++20, and C++Latest language settings.

From C++17 final draft:

28.7 Sorting and related operations

All the operations in 28.7 have two versions: one that takes a function object of type Compare and one that uses an operator<.
Compare is a function object type (23.14). The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type Compare, when contextually converted to bool (Clause 7), yields true if the first argument of the call is less than the second, and false otherwise. Compare comp is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation. It is assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.
For all algorithms that take Compare, there is a version that uses operator< instead. That is, comp(*i, *j) != false defaults to *i < *j != false. For algorithms other than those described in 28.7.3, comp shall induce a strict weak ordering on the values.


28.7.3 lists a number of binary search algorithms (lower_bound, upper_bound,  equal_range and binary_search) and minmax_element is not among them so it's not exempt from the strict weak ordering requirement which means that including NaNs in the range makes your program have undefined behavior.


A STL expert from my team understands the standard so that strictly-weak-ordering is only needed in C++-20 when using std::less.

They understand wrong. The change between C++17 and C++20 was changing the default comparison from < to std::less. It has always been a requirement for whichever comparison is used to be a strict-weak-order.
This change only affects algorithms applied to ranges of pointers, as std::less is defined to use < for everything apart from pointers, where it synthesizes a strict-weak-order. For historical reasons, it is undefined to apply < to pointers to elements of distinct arrays.
